# CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification not fired on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, contacts

I am trying to observe if another application such as Contacts.app performs an update on contacts to update contacts list in my app. The app is a Mac OS X application.

I add observer in AppDelegate.swift using

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.addressBookDidChange(_:)), name: CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

and the selector is

```
@objc func addressBookDidChange(notification:NSNotification){  
    print("Contacts need update!")  
}.
```

I do not observe any output although I update a contact using Contacts.app

Am I missing something?

The OS is macOS Sierra Beta 2.
I use Contacts framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To observe `CNContactStore` notification you should create this store and keep reference.

```
fileprivate var CNContactStore: CNContactStore? = nil

func addObserver() {
    contactStore = CNContactStore()
    NSNotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(addressBookDidChange(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.CNContactStoreDidChange, object: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had done something similar. In fact, probably with following versions of the OS, the problem was automatically solved.